# Howto upgrade manually added packages in reprepro repositories?

Tags: reprepro

I've successfully created a Debian repository wiht reprepro by adding deb files manually with:

```
reprepro --ask-passphrase -V includedeb jessie /tmp/debs/*.deb
```

Now I revived new versions of the debs by the upstream. The upstream does not provide a repository. This is why I want to build my own. My question is:

How to update the packages in my repository with new versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add packages to your pool with newer versions than the ones installed. Unless you're importing from another repo it will keep as many versions as you import. You can just delete them manually.

Comment: Did so, works, but now I find both versions in "pool". How to get rid of the old files?